# shell cd command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, cd

Im trying to execute shell commands using ruby, but i cant change directory to PATH with blank spaces.

```
variable = %x[cd #{ENV["HOME"]}/Virtual\\ VMs/]
```

This is not working.
Thank you

Comment: `variable = %x[cd #{ENV["HOME"]}/Virtual\\ VMs/]` works for me

Comment: Why you just don't use `Dir.chdir` from Ruby std? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#chdir-method

Comment: I used it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely safe:

```
path = File.join [ENV["HOME"], 'Virtual VMs']
variable = %x[cd '#{path}']
```

Please note, that `cd` has empty output, so to make sure it works one probably wants to do smth like:

```
path = File.join [ENV["HOME"], 'Virtual VMs']
variable = %x[cd '#{path}' && ls -la]
#⇒ "total 32\ndrwxr-xr-x  ....."
```

Answer (score 1):

What is ist supposed to do? You try to chdir into a directory, but then don't do anything in it. Your `variable` will be empty in any case. Aside from the fact that it is pointless to do, you can not reliably execute a cd by itself in this way, because it is not an executable file.  You can see this if you just execute `%x[cd]`. You will get an `Errno::ENOENT` exception.

Maybe you should first describe in a broader context, what you want to achieve with your code. Where would you like to change the working directory? Within the Ruby process - in which case you have to use `Dir.chdir` - or in the child process - in which case you have to execute some command after the cd.

Comment: Im trying to check information about virtual machine allocated in: /root/Virtual VMs/folder/folder so first i need to change the directory im working

Comment: i thing that Dir.chdir is the best way but i cant change to path with spaces on it, the system says Message: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir

Comment: Again: `Dir.chdir File.join [ENV["HOME"], 'Virtual VMs']` perfectly works.

Comment: This is the message i get from shell -   Message: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /root/Virtual VMs/tt/holo-master

Comment: There is no way you could get “`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /root/Virtual VMs/` **`tt/holo-master`**” by executing the command above. If you after all want to get an answer, don’t mess with what you are sharing and what you are really executing.

Comment: The directory exists i've checked with listing the contents from shell. 
# ls /root/Virtual VMs/tt/holo-master
# centos-7-1-1.x86_64.vmdk  holo-master.vbox  holo-master.vbox-prev
The code im running in ruby is the following: 
path = File.join [ENV["HOME"], 'Virtual VMs', 'tt,'holo-master']
Dir.chdir("#{path}")

And the error is:
Message: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /root/Virtual VMs/tt/holo-master

Comment: sorry,  guys the problem was an uppercase. Thank you very much.